# web music player that works offline

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, audio-player

I made a web music player for mobiles using as example this page: http://www.lewebmonster.com/crear-un-reproductor-de-musica-con-html5-y-jquery/

What I want now is to give the possibility to the users that already use it to use the music player even when they are offline. How can I make to store the music but only can reproduce it from the music player?

This is the music player that I am talking about: http://playwithme.mobi/music_retro_blue/

Comment: to make it only playable with it you would have to encode the music with some proprietary codec(private codec only usable by your app) or employ some drm scheme before saving.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do you know where I can find an example of something similar? I am not so sure of how to proceed.